# Showing a message only to new installations

Tags: android, jquery, android-activity

I have an app developed on android studio, and when you start its showing a SplashScreen with the icon an a loading bar, and when its done, the app auto start a class called Slider and have 4 sliders for the new users to know how to use the app and then, the user click on a button and redirect to MainActivity, ok, so i want, if a users is old, to don't display the Slider class and redirect automatically to `MainActivity`, I'm saying, to display the slider only for new installations, if anyone can help me.. y tried so many hours an i don't get nothing works... Thanks to all!

Comment: saved a new user boolean in SharedPreferences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only for new installation.

Use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) and store your first installation flag to run your Settings at first time.

Like,

```
private SharedPreferences prefs = null;


private void isFirstTime()
{
        prefs = getSharedPreferences("appPref", MODE_PRIVATE);

        if (prefs.getBoolean("firstInstall", true)) {

             // Your setting activity start here 
             prefs.edit().putBoolean("firstInstall", false).commit();
        }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply man but i dont know why its not working, i need to put that code on MainActivity or in Slider, remember the first class on start is Slider and then when you click on a button you go to MainActivity, here i put the MainActivity code, if you want i can give you Slider code too.
http://pastebin.com/gqPBkfaR

Comment: I suggest you to put this code in `MainActivity` 's `onCreate()` and start Slider on first app install.

Answer (score 0):

Hi maybe i understand your problem, maybe one of more solution:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("com.example.app", context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    //check if the first run of app
    if (prefs.getBoolean("firstrun", true)) {
        // Do first run stuff here then set 'firstrun' as false
        // using the following line to edit/commit prefs

        prefs.edit().putBoolean("firstrun", false).commit();
        //for example i run another class if is the first run
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyClass.class);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

if Slider is the Launcher the in your `Slider.class` use Shared Preference,just add this lines as first lines in your  `public void init(Bundle bundle)` method

```
 SharedPreference pref;
      @Override
       public void init(Bundle bundle) {

            pref =SharedPreference.getSharedPrefernce("APP",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            if(pref.getBoolean("first",false)) // false for first time so it wont start Mainactivity without slider
            {
               SharedPreference.Editor editor= pref.edit();
                editor.putBoolean(true);// from second time it will be false 
               editor.commit();
               Intent in=new Intent(Slider.this,MainActivity.class);
             startActivity(in);
             }

             //Existing Slider Code
         }
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer man but i didnt get it work, i adjunt my MainActivity without the code of SharedPreference:
http://pastebin.com/gqPBkfaR if you can implement it to that code.. that would be awesome if you can, thanks again

Comment: i've updated the code,you using `showslider(this)` to show slider?

Comment: Im sorry for dont telling you the StartAppAd is a code to display ads, its not the meaning of the start app, sorry about that, have set in manifest to start first of all Application.class to subscribe the user to a parse push channel, then the Slider.class and then the MainActivity, and on the Slider.class i set a button to go to MainActivity

Comment: if slider activity is launcher,then do above changes

Comment: Thanks another time man, i tried but i get alot of errors, im not an advanced developer of android studio so please understand my unknowledge.
I give you the slider.class code without your code http://pastebin.com/5CFWseGj

Comment: Well sorry ,ive thought your even extending Activity in your Slider class But your using AppTour ,so update this code in init method ,sorry for inconvenience

Comment: Ok man im getting know how to add well, i give you a screenshot http://prntscr.com/8jm9nx

Comment: Ok i added this now and is working but i think its not setting in false after relaunch:
http://pastebin.com/cSi1Emtx
After that code i put the Slider code

Answer (score 0):

FINALLY I SOLVED THIS!! AFTER COUPLE HOURS.. thanks to everyone.
Finally i put on MainActivity in onCreate this:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = null;
    {
        prefs = getSharedPreferences("com.sorte.app", MODE_PRIVATE);

        if (prefs.getBoolean("firstInstall", true)) {

            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Slide.class);
            startActivity(i);
            prefs.edit().putBoolean("firstInstall", false).commit();
        }
    }
```